# vba lookup to lookup info in a spread sheet

Tags: vba, lookup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzNG7.png)Hi im trying to make a lookup for myself but am having a bit of trouble,

```
 Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
 Dim cell As Range
 Dim iRow As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

 If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("A:A"), Me.textbox_GRN1.Value) = 0 
 Then
 MsgBox "This is and incorrect GRN"
 Me.textbox_GRN1.Value = ""
 Exit Sub
 End If
 Dim rng As Range

 Set rng = ws.Range("A2")

 With ws
    Me.textbox_BAY1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, 
ws.Range("B1:B65536").Value, 1, False)
    Me.textbox_ROW1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, ws.Range("C1:C65536").Value, 1, False)
    Me.textbox_COLOUM1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, ws.Range("D1:D65536").Value, 1, False)
    Me.textbox_PALLET1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, ws.Range("E1:E65536").Value, 1, False)
 End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: we will need more information than `having a bit of trouble`.  What specifically is the code supposed to do?  Where is it failing?  What errors are you getting and on which line?  Please add the answers to these questions in the original post using [edit]

Comment: its just a vba lookup that looks at the text box GRN then grabs the info in the same row and puts in in the corresponding text boxs

Comment: That does not tell me what is wrong and where the error occurs, we are not mind readers.

Comment: That's not how VLOOKUP works - you should pass it a table that *includes the column you want to return a value from*

Comment: sorry im new to this, the error is it dosen't grab the info just keeps telling me to debug, i can send an image if that helps with what im trying to do

Comment: debug dialog tells you the error  ...press `debug` ... yellow line is where fault lies

Comment: look lets just scrap the code i have above, how would i go by making a VLOOKUP that actually works, i want to put a value in a text box (GRN) and then receive the correct info from the row the GRN is inline with in the text boxs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

     Dim cell As Range, GRN
     Dim iRow As Long
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

     GRN = Me.textbox_GRN1.Value

     If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("A:A"), GRN) = 0 Then
         MsgBox "This is an incorrect GRN"
         'Me.textbox_GRN1.Value = "" 'Don't do this! 
                                     'It will annoy your users
         Exit Sub
     End If

     Dim rng As Range
     Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'assumes no blank rows/columns in data table

    Me.textbox_BAY1.Value = Application.VLookup(GRN, rng, 2, False) 
    Me.textbox_ROW1.Value = Application.VLookup(GRN, rng, 3, False) 
    Me.textbox_COLOUM1.Value = Application.VLookup(GRN, rng, 4, False) 
    Me.textbox_PALLET1.Value = Application.VLookup(GRN, rng, 5, False) 

End Sub
```

I would prefer something like this though:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim f As Range, GRN

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    GRN = Me.textbox_GRN1.Value

    Set f = ws.Columns(1).Find(GRN, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If f Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "This is an incorrect GRN"
        'Me.textbox_GRN1.Value = "" 'Don't do this!
                                    'It will annoy your users
        'you should probably clear the other textboxes here though
    Else
       With f.EntireRow
           Me.textbox_BAY1.Value = .Cells(2).Value
           Me.textbox_ROW1.Value = .Cells(3).Value
           Me.textbox_COLOUM1.Value = .Cells(4).Value
           Me.textbox_PALLET1.Value = .Cells(5).Value
       End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: didn't work,

Run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)':
Could not set the Value property. Type mismatch.